# Why does $\frac{p+2q}{p+q}$ approximate $\sqrt 2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

I recently found out that starting with $\frac{1}{1}$ and letting $p$ be the numerator and $q$ the denominator, then you can generate a sequence that approximates $\sqrt 2$ using:

$$\frac{p+2q}{p+q}$$

The first few terms of the sequence are:

$\frac{1}{1}$, $\frac{3}{2}$, $\frac{7}{5}$, $\frac{17}{12}$, $\frac{41}{29}$, $\frac{99}{70}$, $...$

But why is this case?

Comment: Hint:  $p^2-2q^2=\pm1$

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/730349/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/818845/42969

Comment: If you are familiar with eigenvectors and eigenvalues, you can also start with $\begin{pmatrix}p_{n+1} \\ q_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}p_{n} \\ q_{n}\end{pmatrix}$ from which we derive $\begin{pmatrix}p_{n} \\ q_{n}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^n \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Also related: the secant method and group laws on conics - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141941/242) on Rudin's example.